Issue with iframe Authentication in ASP.NET MVC across different origins
I have two ASP.NET MVC websites hosted on different IIS servers (not sharing the same origin). In the first website, I am using an iframe to embed the second website. When trying to log in to the second website (inside the iframe), I enter the user credentials, but upon successful login, it redirects back to the login page instead of the home page. I checked the cookies in the browser storage and found that they are not being created.
Please help me this issue.

You can't use <iframe> elements like this anymore due to browsers now blocking third-party cookies. You will need to use top-level page redirections instead.

could you share how you are setting the cookie. as @dai said Recent browser updates require that cookies set by the second website must explicitly allow cross-site access. set the SameSiteMode.None. set the cors code to allow cross origin in the .net app and in iis. set the custom response header Name:Content-Security-Policy and  Value: frame-ancestors 'self' https://first-website-domain.com;

check console logs if you still facing issue
